# Apache config that does: Try docroot #1. File not found? Try docroot #2. File not found? 404

Tags: apache, redirect, webserver, virtualhost, http-status-code-404

I'd like to be able to set a DocumentRoot for my VH that redirects all "not found" requests to another DocumentRoot altogether. But I don't want a redirect -- the URL needs to stay the same.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there some reason you couldn't use a script to do this? Check for each file in turn based on the params passed, then either stream the file or send a 404. You could even use URL rewriting and have the paths simply appear to be the normal file names.

This just strikes me as something more appropriate for the application to do than the configuration.

Comment: Docroot #1 will be a store of static files. Docroot #2 will contain the app, including CakePHP and Magento, both of which need that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` setting to be correct.

Comment: I gave you the answer for this question and started a new one with waaaay more detail: http://serverfault.com/questions/219938/apache-config-that-uses-two-document-roots-based-on-whether-the-requested-resourc